# Using only 1 columns values to plot histogram in R

Tags: r

I have a CSV with 2 columns, first column showing number of tweets an account has made and the second showing the account name.

```
1    billy
8    johno
3    bobby
1    Rob
```

I'm trying to plot the frequency of amount of tweets. So 1 tweet would have a frequency of 2.

Here's my current code.

```
UniqFreq <-read.csv("Uniq.csv", header = FALSE)
hist(x=UniqFreq[,1], freq = TRUE)
```

Problem is currently my histogram looks like garbage. It x axis is like 250 long which is way out of proportion.

Any help or advice on using the first column of data to plot the frequency of the numbers on a histogram would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**INPUT**

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,4,1), name = c("bob","john","bob","james"))
df
#   value  name
# 1     1   bob
# 2     2  john
# 3     4   bob
# 4     1 james
```

---

**I. Tweet Count Frequency**

```
df
#   value  name
# 1     1   bob
# 2     2  john
# 3     4   bob
# 4     1 james

vec <- table(df$value)
vec
# 1 2 4 
# 2 1 1 

xx <- barplot(table(df$value), xlab = "Tweet Count", ylab = "Frequency of Tweet Counts", main = "Frequency of Tweets posted \nBased on Tweet Count", cex.main = 1, ylim = c(0,10))
text(x = xx, y = vec, label = vec, pos = 3, cex = 1, col = "blue")
```

[image]

---

**II. Tweet Count per person**

```
df
#   value  name
# 1     1   bob
# 2     2  john
# 3     4   bob
# 4     1 james

vec <- tapply(df$value, df$name, sum)
vec
# bob james  john 
#   5     1     2 

xx <- barplot(vec, ylim = c(0,10), main = "Count of tweets per person")
text(x = xx, y = vec, label = vec, pos = 3, cex = 1, col = "blue")
```

[image]

---

Comment: Maybe I worded my question poorly. I want the x axis to have numbers of tweets from 1 -> n. So since 2 people have each posted 1 tweet then the x axis value for 1 has a freq of 2.

Comment: Understood. Will udpate

Comment: Updated it. Please check. Both kinds are there.

Comment: Thank you for this! If my column doesn't have a heading what can i replace the word "value" with?

Comment: Updated again. You can say Tweet Count or Tweet Value and then while plotting frequency of tweet count or just frequency on y axis for tweet counts on x axis.

Comment: For your example you have your data in df and the value column has a heading. Would i replace df with Uniq.csv and leave out the heading since i don't have one

Comment: `names(df)[1] <- "value"` Assign it a name or you can assign it `value` as shown here and for second column together you can say. 
`names(df) <- c("value","name")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157185/discussion-between-sowmya-s-manian-and-liam).

Answer (score 0):

Your data

```
df <- read.table(text="1    billy
8    johno
3    bobby
1    Rob", header=FALSE)
```

Solution using `ggplot` and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  count(V1) %>% 
  ggplot(data=., aes(x=factor(V1), y=n)) + 
    geom_col() +
    xlab("Tweet Count") +
    ylab("Frequency") +
    ggtitle("Frequency of Tweet Counts") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    theme_classic()
```